# Where do I put my XML beans in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

I'm getting back into Spring (currently v4). It's all wonderful now with `@SpringBootApplication` and the other annotations but all the documentation seems to forget to mention how I define other beans in XML!

For example I'd like to create an "SFTP Session Factory" as defined at:
   http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html

There is a nice bit of XML to define the bean but where on earth do I put it and how do I link it in? Previously I did a:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
```

to specify the file name and location but now that I'm trying to use:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
```

Where do I put the XML file? Is there a magic spring name to call it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As long as you're starting with a base `@Configuration` class to begin with, which it maybe sounds like you are with `@SpringBootApplication`, you can use the [`@ImportResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) annotation to include an XML configuration file as well.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-sftp-config.xml")
public class SpringConfiguration {
  //
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put @ImportResource on top of every spring application and test case I write or is there a default name/location that spring automatically looks in?

Comment: @DavidNewcomb You just need to make sure that a configuration class with the annotation is reachable from your configuration root. If it's something you use all the time, you might even add your own autoconfiguration class for it.

Comment: @DavidNewcomb you traditionally only want one `@SpringBootApplication` in your application, as it itself is a combination of `@Configuration` and a few other must-haves.  Your `@ImportResource` only needs to be on a single `@Configuration` class that gets scanned by Spring, just like the auto-scanning that happens / happened in XML land.

Comment: you saved my day.

Comment: I read that the one thing `Spring Boot` is very good at is making the "configuration" process easy and that it can be used without involving configuration `xml` at all, but `xml` can join the configuration process by applying what @bvulaj mentioned. Is it possible to fully configure my application without the use of any `xml`?

Comment: @Mike I would say that most modern Spring Boot apps use zero xml.

Answer (score 3):

You also can translate the XML config to a Java config. In your case it would look like:

```
@Bean
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setPrivateKey(new ClassPathResource("classpath:META-INF/keys/sftpTest"));
    factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase("springIntegration");
    factory.setPort(22);
    factory.setUser("kermit");
    return factory;
}
```

You can put this method in the class with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot ideal concept is avoid xml file. but if you want to keep xml bean, you can just add `@ImportResource("classPath:beanFileName.xml")`.

I would recommend remove the `spring-sftp-config.xml` file. And, convert this file to spring annotation based bean. So, whatever class has been created as bean. Just write `@Service` or `@Component` annotation before class name. for example:

XML based:

```
<bean ID="id name" class="com.example.Employee">
```

Annotation:

```
@Service or @Component
class Employee{
}
```

And, add `@ComponentScan("Give the package name")`. This is the best approach.

Comment: The question was "How do I link in existing xml files?" and not "How do I convert all my beans to annotations?". Your answer is the same as bvulaj's.

Comment: Please add this is a ~comment~ if you are pro-annotation vs xml.  By the way, not everyone agrees with you.  http://literatejava.com/spring/explicit-vs-implicit-configuration-spring/  #justSayin #notHatin

Comment: Nope. Avoiding XML is not ideal. I have SQL, SAS scripts,  HTML blocks  in String beans in XML context files, exploiting the the context variable substitution feature.

Comment: Add @ImportResource("classpath:beanFileName.xml"), not @ImportResource("classPath:beanFileName.xml")