# specific overload of SpringApplication.run is missing in spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to upgrade an application from spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE to spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.

I have this following code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, RedisAutoConfiguration.class})
public class NiceBootApplicationWithoutDB extends AbstractBootApplication {

    public static final String APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML = "classpath:/META-INF/application-context-nodb.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML, getFullArgList(args));
    }

}
```

The overload of `SpringApplication.run(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML, getFullArgList(args))` is:

```
/**
 * Static helper that can be used to run a {@link SpringApplication} from the
 * specified source using default settings.
 * @param source the source to load
 * @param args the application arguments (usually passed from a Java main method)
 * @return the running {@link ApplicationContext}
 */
public static ConfigurableApplicationContext run(Object source, String... args) {
    return run(new Object[] { source }, args);
}

/**
 * Static helper that can be used to run a {@link SpringApplication} from the
 * specified sources using default settings and user supplied arguments.
 * @param sources the sources to load
 * @param args the application arguments (usually passed from a Java main method)
 * @return the running {@link ApplicationContext}
 */
public static ConfigurableApplicationContext run(Object[] sources, String[] args) {
    return new SpringApplication(sources).run(args);
}
```

Both the overloads are not present in spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.

**My question is -** How do I upgrade the above code?

Comment: The SpringApplication [constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#SpringApplication-java.lang.Class...-) and [run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.String:A-) method now use a `Class<?>[] primarySources` argument... did you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right : the API of the `SpringApplication` class in the version 2 of Spring Boot doesn't provide an equivalence.
So no direct way to provide a  XML Spring configuration file.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677553/where-do-i-put-my-xml-beans-in-a-spring-boot-application), you could annotate your Spring Boot class with  [`@ImportResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html).

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/application-context-nodb.xml")
```

It works as `@Import` but that it imports XML spring configuration files instead of class files.

**Javadoc information** :

> Indicates one or more resources containing bean definitions to import.
>
> Like `@Import`, this annotation provides functionality similar to the
>    element in Spring XML. It is typically used when designing
>   `@Configuration` classes to be bootstrapped by an
>   `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, but where some XML functionality
>   such as namespaces is still necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation `@ImportResource`for import configuration XML

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, RedisAutoConfiguration.class})
    @ImportResource(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML)
    public class NiceBootApplicationWithoutDB extends AbstractBootApplication {

        public static final String APPLICATION_CONTEXT_XML = "classpath:/META-INF/application-context-nodb.xml";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(AbstractBootApplication.class, getFullArgList(args));
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Why you are using `SpringApplication.main` instead of `SpringApplication.run` ?

Comment: Sorry for that, copy past from my IDE... of course we should use run, without configuration source class it will not works. If we wanna use main we should add configuration in parameters for main method

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Configuration class like this, that will take in considération your spring xml confiiguration :)

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class XmlConfiguration {

}
```